# Word for the aspect of an object which makes it different from a group of otherwise identical objects

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I have these three statements:

1. "John likes pasta."
2. "Mary likes pasta."
3. "Joseph likes pasta."

For these three sentences with the format "[name] likes pasta", I'm looking for a word for the "[name]" with respect to the fact that this particular part of the sentence is the only thing which makes it different from the other two.

The usage I would imagine is this:

> The *word* of sentence 1 is "John".

For context, the word I am looking for is to be used as a parameter name for a function which takes a string and embeds it into a template string, similar to the following:

```
function embedInSentence(word_here) = word_here + " likes pasta."
```

I remember a book I had about cars when I was younger described "exterior identification points" of different models, which could be used to tell that particular one from another model/trim level. It's the closest thing I have to a fitting word or phrase, but it's quite long and doesn't fit my use case – I'm looking for a more abstract term, such as "identification point" but as a single word.

Comment: Parameter? Key? Variable? ID?

Comment: @Yosef These seem applicable only in the programming context, so are still useful, but don't address the "more abstract term" part.

Comment: The naming of computer program variables or classes is considered [off topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not looking specifically for the name for the variable, that was simply what started me looking for the word. I only included that in my question as a bit of extra context to go with the first example.

Comment: That is stated to be the use case. I am tempted to say that *word* of sentence 1 is *subject* but perhaps more helpful would be **differentiator** – "the thing which makes it different."

Comment: @WeatherVane I think _differentiator_ fits very well here. Feel free to make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that distinguishes can be called (from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/differentiator)) a

> **differentiator**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** Something that enables a difference or distinction to be made.